# How to convert a spark dataframe into a http response in JSON format

Tags: java, spring, rest, apache-spark

My use case is as follows. When the HTTP endpoint is hit, it will read a Parquet file, convert to Spark dataframe/other framework dataframe, run some simple processing and output it in response in JSON format.

**EDITED**
Adding datasets - they range from small, under 100 rows * 10 columns, to medium 500,000 rows * 20 columns, column value are text and numerical numbers
So open to other suggestions.  I am trying Arrow, Spark .

I tried dataset.write and it writes to file. I wonder if there is a way to convert it to either

1. JSON string, might be some mapper?
2. direct stream to HTTP output stream

Or maybe I shouldn't use Spark?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `write`, you have plenty of methods in `Dataset` which can collect all data on the driver (collect, collectAsList, toLocalIterator - [spark javadoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#collectAsList--)). Just don't forget that all your data should fit in driver memory or you will get OOM.

After collecting all data you need on the driver you can handle it as any java object(e.g. serialize it to JSON) and send as response.

Here is an example

```java
List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<>();

rows.add(RowFactory.create("1", "name"));
rows.add(RowFactory.create("2", "name2"));
rows.add(RowFactory.create("3", "name3"));

StructType schema = new StructType();
schema = schema.add("id", DataTypes.StringType, false);
schema = schema.add("name", DataTypes.StringType, false);

Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema);

List<String> res = df.withColumn(
        "struct",
        functions.struct(functions.col("id"), functions.col("name"))
).withColumn(
        "json",
        functions.to_json(functions.col("struct"))
).select("json").collectAsList().stream().map(
        row -> row.getString(0)
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Re: OOM, I am afraid some of them might be quite large so wonder if I could directly stream that to the http output pipe